# Problem producing Avro serialized object through kafka-avro-console-producer

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, oracle-golden-gate

I'm **producing** a message by **using** the **kafka-avro-console-producer** binary by doing:

```
kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list broker:9092 --topic example-topic --property schema.registry.url='http://schema-registry:8081 --property value.schema='{"type": "record","name": "test","fields": [{"name": "before", "type": ["null", {"type": "record", "name": "columns", "fields":[{"name": "name", "type": "string"}]}],"default": "null"},{"name": "after", "type": ["null", "columns"],"default": "null"}]}'
{"before": null,"after": {"name": "John"}}'
```

sending the **following message**:

```
{"before": null,"after": {"name": "John"}}
```

and by appling the following **Avro schema**:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "test",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "before",
        "type": ["null", {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "columns",
            "fields": [{
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string"
            }]
        }],
        "default": "null"
    }, {
        "name": "after",
        "type": ["null", "columns"],
        "default": "null"
    }]
}
```

**the error** I'm getting in return is the following:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch name
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readIndex(JsonDecoder.java:445)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:290)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:178)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:230)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.jsonToAvro(AvroMessageReader.java:213)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readMessage(AvroMessageReader.java:180)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:55)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
```

---

For those of you that are willing to go deeper into the rabbit hole, I'm making an **integration between Oracle Golden Gate and Apache Kafka** by using the Oracle Golden Gate Big Data connector. I'm currently experiencing problems with an equivalent model of the one described in here:

https://www.ateam-oracle.com/oracle-goldengate-big-data-adapter-apache-kafka-producer

When trying to apply the **schema described in the above webpage to it's corresponding model**(and after completing the JSON model), **I'm getting the same error** as the one I'm getting with the model and schema in the question.

---

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem

```
"type": ["null", "columns"]
```

You cannot refer back to other record types. You'll need to expand that out like you did for the other field

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @cricket_007. I'm going to test the schema duplicating the model instead of refering back to "columns" type.

Comment: Thank you again, I've tested your solution and it did the trick!